# A question regarding the ratio test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

If I want to prove that $\sum x_i$ diverges and the ratio test yields $\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i} \to k > 1$ then we're done but if $k \to \infty$ what then? Does the ratio test work when the limit blows up to infinity as well? I mean we can't say that $k > 1$ if $k \to \infty$ because wouldn't that essentially be like saying that $\infty > 1$ which is wrong since infinity cannot be treated like a normal number?

Comment: What you need [not for divergence, but for the applicability of the ratio test] is $\liminf \frac{\lvert x_{k+1}\rvert}{\lvert x_k\rvert} > 1$ (or $\limsup \frac{\lvert x_{k+1}\rvert}{\lvert x_k\rvert} < 1$ for convergence). The existence of a limit (be it in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$) is not important. But if the limit is $+\infty$, that of course is sufficient.

Comment: If $k \to +\infty$, then surely $k > 1$ so the conclusion (of divergence) holds.

Comment: How would one go about proving this? The proof that was given in my real analysis book was only based on the limit existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test can be generalized slightly to a different form:

> We says that a series $\sum x_n$ diverges if exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that
>
> $$x_n\neq 0\text{ and }\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|}\ge 1,\;\forall n\ge N\tag{1}$$
>
> Alternatively the series converges absolutely if exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that
>
> $$x_n\neq 0\text{ and }\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|}< 1,\;\forall n\ge N$$
>
> Other cases are not conclusive.

From this point of view you can check that if $\lim\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|}=\infty$ then exists some $N$ such that the condition $(1)$ holds, then the series diverges.