# convergence of a power series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(2n)!}{(3n+1)!}x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(2n)!}{(3n+1)!}x^n}$$

I've already use that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(2(n+1)!)}{(3(n+1)+1)!}x^{(n+1)}}{\frac{(2n)!}{(3n+1)!}x^n}\right|=\frac{2}{3}|x|$$

then, the series converges with $-3/2<x<3/2$, but i have troubles with $x=\pm 3/2$ any idea, cuz I don't see how can I prove o refute de convergence in this points.

Comment: Well, I've use the comparsion criterion to choose the convergence ratio (-3/2,3/2) but I'm still confuse in the extreme values of this interval...

Comment: You did the ratio test wrong (check those factorials)

Comment: Check [this generalized definition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015218/a-question-regarding-the-ratio-test/2015248#2015248) of the ratio test.

Answer (score 3):

Try your limit again; it is

$$\frac{\displaystyle\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)\cdot(2n)!}{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)\cdot(3n+1)!}\cdot x^{n+1}}{\displaystyle\frac{(2n)!}{(3n+1)!}\cdot x^n}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)}x$$

Notice that as $n\to\infty$ the fraction $\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)}\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{\frac{(2(n+1)!)}{(3(n+1)+1)!}x^{(n+1)}}{\frac{(2n)!}{(3n+1)!}x^n}\right|=\frac{2 (2n+1) }{3 \left(9 n^2+18n+8\right)}\:|x| \to 0
$$the given series admits an *infinite radius of convergence* by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test).

Comment: Ugh, all of you beat me :D